# calling function from ajax post response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using a graph [library](http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/graph/examples/example01_basis.html) which is using javascript. I have to run this script after getting the data with another ajax script. But when I use the script

```
    var request, response;

    var newUrl = url + '/thermometer/getLastHourData';
    var data =  $.ajax({
                    url: newUrl,
                    data: request,
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: "post",
                    success: function(data) {
                        drawGraph();
                        return data;
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Error occured');
                    }
            });
```

Also the drawGraph function is

```
    google.load("visualization", "1");

    // Set callback to run when API is loaded
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    // Called when the Visualization API is loaded.
    function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate a data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('datetime', 'time');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Function A');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Function B');

        function functionA(x) {
            return Math.sin(x / 25) * Math.cos(x / 25) * 50 + (Math.random()-0.5) * 10;
        }

        function functionB(x) {
            return Math.sin(x / 50) *50 + Math.cos(x / 7) * 75 + (Math.random()-0.5) * 20 + 20;
        }

        // create data
        var d = new Date(2010, 9, 23, 20, 0, 0);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            data.addRow([new Date(d), functionA(i), functionB(i)]);
            d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 1);
        }

        // specify options
        var options = {
            "width":  "100%",
            "height": "350px"
        };

        // Instantiate our graph object.
        var graph = new links.Graph(document.getElementById('mygraph'));

        // Draw our graph with the created data and options
        graph.draw(data, options);
    }
```

(I did not change it what I need to since checking the code is running correctly)

drawGraph start to wait for loading google.com for some library but when I use the function drawGraph without calling from the ajax function, it works as in the link that I mention at the begining.

How can I call this graph function from ajax  without problem ?

Comment: did you try to call `google.load("visualization", "1");` instead of `drawGraph();`?

Comment: yes I have tried. Also the main problem is calling that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all clear what you question is here. However if you are having problems with the asynchronous properties of ajax, simply modify your ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: newUrl,
      data: request,
      async: false,

etc, etc, etc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just did not think about that. That solution has solved my problem. Thanks a lot.